# Botaniq grass on the road

Tags: add-on

Grass grows on the road. I'm using the [Botaniq](https://blendermarket.com/products/botaniq-trees) full addon. How to place the grass only on the plane? Boolean modifier doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: From downloaded free addon, I can see a grass object is a cluster of wheats as single object and distributed by particle system. So each particle distributes this wheat cluster. This cluster has an origin at a center. When particle system distributes points they can be released close to border and since each point is represent by grass cluster it easily appears as part of this cluster is outside original (distribution) object.

Comment: Yes, that right. But can I solve it somehow? I was trying to cut the gress with Boolean modifier. But that didn´t work.

Answer (score 1):

When you place a grass, in Outliner window you can see several objects:

- Collection of grass objects (named Grass_Basic...)
- and actual plane object distributing objects from collection.
  (named pps_Grass ... "pps" probably **p**lane's **p**article **s**ystem)

Each objects in this collection is a cluster of grass wheats with Origin at center of this cluster.

[image]

Each object in collection is used to be rendered at a point distributed by particle system. Since particles can be released close to plane border, the cluster rendered with center at particle position partly place the grass cluster out of plane.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that right. But can I solve it somehow? I was trying to cut the gress with Boolean modifier. But that didn´t work.

Comment: Solution depends how complex part you need to solve. If it is just a strip, seen in your screenshot, make it narrower ... or you can try extend material node tree with a few nodes - make it transparent in that part. I can extend my answer if you are interested (or if does it make sense in your case)... nothing for very close up look :)

Answer (score 0):

You could select the row of faces closest to the road.  Then hit p to make them their own object. Then place new grass just on that strip and scale down the grass so that it does cover the road.  This could give a it a nice "edge trimmer" effect which could add to the realism of the scene.  Just a thought